# Custom css for entire Google Chrome browser

Tags: css, browser

Is it possible to change CSS that google Chrome apply to websites.

I want to hide some elements for example on facebook to dont see it, becouse it eats half of my free time.

Something like
`.facebook-wall{display:none;}` -auto applied everytime I go to fb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) is a good extension. You can interactively build some custom CSS to apply to your choice of website.

It even seems to have an accompanying website where other people have shared their concoctions, so possibly somebody has already put together something to filter down Facebook feeds.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understand you correctly...

- This isn't for a website you're making
- This is only for your own personal use

Use Tampermonkey.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en

It's supposed to work much like Greasemonkey (the Firefox add-on), and it should meet your needs.